# I need a tool like Task Manager that shows top applications that are taking CPU

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, desktop-gadget

I need a light weight tool (somehow like Task Manager) or desktop gadget that shows top applications that are taking CPU. Task Manager is not so good because it lists ALL applications, and that is a laaaarge list. I need a tool that shows only the top first 4-5 applications in the order of their hungriness.

Maybe you can make a recommendation.
Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

I already know about Task Manager. Please do not link to programs similar to it (that list ALL applications). I need something like 'top' command in linux - but with GUI because this is why we all love Windows (hehe).

Here is the description of linux 'top':

> top provides an ongoing look at
>   processor activity in real time. It
>   displays a listing of the most
>   CPU-intensive tasks on the system...

Comment: Which flavour of Windows are you using? There may already be something at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets

Comment: Hi ChrisF. I just looked there few minutes ago. I have Win 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [TopProcess](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=681102c2-5dde-44d2-a33a-96dbff32517a), it seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: You are the best! It looks like this is the tool I need! I install it right now.

Comment: And... accepted.

Comment: The link to TopProcess isn't valid anymore. Do you know a better place for it?

Comment: Right here: https://github.com/bhollis/TopProcess

Answer (score 1):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) has what you are looking for, you can sort by CPU usage and it will list in order by the top applications using the CPU.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not much different than Task Manager. I don't want a list of ALL programs. Plus, the programs can also be sorted by CPU in Task Manager. My need is different. Question updated.

Comment: `top` is basically Task Manager with the CPU sort enabled. It's the exact same thing. By sorting by CPU usage, you are listing the programs by order of most intensive usage.

Comment: it displays only top applications that takes most cpu so it is not the same as TaskManager

Comment: `top` displays all running apps, regardless of even if they are consuming CPU. So, yes, it's the same idea. There is no single-purpose program to do what you want. Just sort by the CPU usage, that's what `top` and `htop` do on linux.

Comment: @Altar: By default, `top` lists processes until it runs out of screen space.  If your terminal has more lines, you get more output.  So you could have just as easily used taskman/procexp, changed the sort, and made the window as large or small as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[Systernals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can do this too. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I have it. But it is not much different than Task Manager. I don't want a list of ALL programs.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Ok, did you try some of these? http://alternativeto.net/software/htop/

Comment: `htop` is for linux, OP wants list for Windows.